# need help on angular 7 Observable async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, url-routing, angular-universal

Im trying to achieve page source wait from API call

```
    public responseTop: Observable<any>;
    this.responseTop = this.productSRV.topEquipments();
    this.responseTop.toPromise().then(sucess => {
        this.topEquipments = sucess['data'];
        // console.log('eq');
        // console.log(this.topEquipments);
        this.newsletterForm.controls.recaptchaReactive.setValue(sucess['message']);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error!', error);
    });

  <ng-container *ngFor="let topEq of topEquipments;">
```

as API is calling two times and how to put | async to wait for page source for SEO
If i put

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="responseTop | async">
```

still it will not load in page source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you call `.then` you execute it first time, when you use `async` it executes it second time.

The question is - what is desired behavior?

I would advise to combine them together:

```js
public responseTop: Observable<any>;
this.responseTop = this.productSRV.topEquipments().pipe(
  // side effect
  tap(success => this.newsletterForm.controls.recaptchaReactive.setValue(success['message'])),   

  // mapping result to the array we need
  tap(console.log),
  map(success => success['data']),

  // catching error
  catchError(error => {
    console.log('Error!', error);
    throw error;
  }),
);
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="responseTop | async as topEquipments">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let topEq of topEquipments">
    {{ topEq | json }}
  </ng-container> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: behavior is to achieve topEquiment generated html should appear in page source when doing build:ssr and serve:ssr. 

catchError giving me this error
Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.ts(2345)

Comment: does it throw the error if you comment `tap`? Also might you share source of `productSRV.topEquipments()`?

Comment: "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",

I'm using this versions of rxjs

  topEquipments() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}topCategories`, this.helperSRV.getHeaders(true)).pipe(map(this.extractData));
  }

Comment: that's fine, I think the problem is in place where the definition happens, or side effects it causes.

Comment: HomepageComponent.html:117 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
When doing without catchError
this.responseTop = this.productSRV.topEquipments().pipe(
  // side effect
  tap(success => this.newsletterForm.controls.recaptchaReactive.setValue(sucess['message']),   

  // mapping result to the array we need
  map(success => success['data']),

 )
);
i think one parenthesis also missing

output from api
data: 
0: {...}
1: {...}
2: {…}
3: {...}
error: []
message: "SMG"

Comment: aha, so it works, but `success['data']` isn't an array.
might you share what `success` is?

Comment: `  tap(success => this.newsletterForm.controls.recaptchaReactive.setValue(sucess['message'])),   `

kindly update the code spelling mistake sucess['message'] to success ['message']

Comment: is there specific reason it is working fine when i do build:ssr serve:ssr at local it is working fine generating html but not at dev server

Comment: to be honest, it can be caused by a lot of issues, I would recommend to use a docker image. With it you can test it locally and you can be sure that deployed version is the same. If you can't use docker - then try to user docker locally only by using the same server OS and nodejs version. Perhaps it helps to reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: not understanding why it is behaving like this, it need to be in html but not there :(

Comment: can we do without *ngIf?

Comment: to create a context in a template - can't say for sure, but I don't know another way than ngIf.

Comment: I meant I don't know other way than `responseTop | async as topEquipments`, that's already in the answer.

Comment: try to adapt code from the answer in your app, then it will do just a single call.

Comment: is it same for angular 9? @satanTime

Comment: @ShafqatJan yep, it’s rather about rxjs than about angular.

Comment: i dont know why my page is not waiting for api call in angular in lazy loading

Comment: might you create a stackblitz example?

Comment: https://machinesrentals.com/ can you see why it is loading 2 times, im using lazy loading and ModuleMapLoaderModule, with out lazy loadiong it is fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65233739/after-using-modulemaploadermodule-page-is-loading-twice

Comment: Ah, it's about SSR, unfortunately, I don't have experience with it.